# Call a JavaScript function using <select> name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid in asp.net. In this grid I am adding paging. In the paging footer I am showing a dropdown dynamically. The drop down contains the values (10,25,50,100). Now I want to  capture the dropdown value and according to that value I want to do some change page styles. But here I am not getting any id of the dropdown list.

Here is my select code

```
<select style="text-align:right;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgBatting$ctl13$ctl26\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dgBatting$ctl13$ctl26">
<option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In `onchange` you can use `this` to reference the dropdown.

Comment: Why do set a timer of 0 seconds ?
You should ask your __doPostBack method directly instead.

You can easily access the dropdown value using jQuery in this way:
$('#your-select').val() or as David said, $(this).val().

Comment: i dont see id attribute attached to select?

Comment: am not getting any id to the dropdown.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with why you're trying to do it this way.  Set `AutoPostBack` to true (which it is by default) and handle the change event with server-side code.

Comment: What do you mean by "am not getting any id to the dropdown"?

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<select id="ftselect">
<option value="MostRecent">MostRecent</option>
<option value="MostLiked">MostLiked</option> 
 <option value="Relavance">Relavance</option>
<option value="MostViewed">MostViewed</option> </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("select").change(function () {

      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str = $(this).text();
          });        

    })
    .change();
```